# How do I use fastcgi with the apache2 charm?

Tags: apache2, juju

I need use mod-fastcgi, How i can config with the juju precise apache2 ?

I use :

```
juju set apache2 enable_modules=fastcgi
```

return by juju debug-log :

```
unit-apache2-1: 2014-08-06 01:37:42 INFO config-changed E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
unit-apache2-1: 2014-08-06 01:37:42 INFO juju-log Installing module fastcgi failed
unit-apache2-1: 2014-08-06 01:37:42 INFO config-changed Module status disabled.
unit-apache2-1: 2014-08-06 01:37:42 INFO config-changed To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
unit-apache2-1: 2014-08-06 01:37:42 INFO config-changed   service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

According to apache2 documentation in precise - http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/precise/apache2, you are calling the command correctly to enable the fastcgi module, but it seems the libapache2-mod-fastcgi cannot be installed.

Can you try `juju ssh apache2/1` and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi`? This might fix the issue with the package.

If not, you can consider upgrading the charm or using a Trusty machine instead and the trusty version of the charm, as the issue might be fixed in a newer revision of the charm.